# Facebook different users posting to different pages as the page itself

Tags: facebook-graph-api, post

I have a facebook application and want to use it to allow my users to post simple messages on a page.
I used api explorer and made a few api calls to post but all that I post is not visible for other users than the one I am logged with and for not-logged-in users. I want my api-made posts  to be visible for everyone, not just for the user that posted them.

I mention that if I make a post using the textbox directly (manually) on the page then those posts are visible to everyone, even for non-logged-in.

Is there a step-by-step tutorial for this?

What I finally want is to allow users of my site to post messages to facebook directly (after login to facebook of course). Posts should be done by different users to different pages as the respective page.

Code samples are much appreciated.

Comment: For posting to a page _as_ the page, get a page access token: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: I have read those docs but there they talk about a page admin granting manage_pages permission to my application. But users that will be posting through my app (and thus will be logged in and asked to grant permission) will not be admins of those pages they want to post to. How does admin become aware that someone wants to log in to fb and use my app to post to the page he/she administers in the moment the user logs in so that he/she(admin) can grant that permission that very moment to the logging-in user? Anyone can post to a facebook page, not just admins.

Comment: Whether or not anyone can post to a page, depends on the page’s settings. But to post _as_ the page, you need an access token with `manage_pages` permission. And there’s no build-in way for a page admin to get notified when someone wants to post to their page as the page, because that’s not a common use case. But the page admin can grant you `manage_pages` once so you get a page access token, and then you can use that in your app to post to the page, you just have to set that access token explicitly when doing so.

Comment: I see. But how do I get the page access token? I have read that I have tu use a GET with /me/accounts after user login, which would return a list of pages that the user is admin of, together with the page access tokens. But those accounts will belong to the user that has logged in not to the admin of the page I need. Do I need to talk to the admin to get a page access token ?

Comment: Yes, of course you have to get it from an admin of the page you are wanting to post to as the page.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, add this as an answer and I will give you credits for it.

Answer (score 0):

For posting to a page as the page, get a page access token: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

To post as the page, you need an access token with `manage_pages` permission. And there’s no build-in way for a page admin to get notified when someone wants to post to their page as the page, because that’s not a common use case. But the page admin can grant you `manage_pages` once so you get a page access token, and then you can use that in your app to post to the page, you just have to set that access token explicitly when doing so.